# How can i make Twitter's row menu in iOS app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Anybody can tell me how to make Twitter's row menu in iOS app like img below?

[image]

This menu appear when i touch down move finger to left (Touch in UITableCell of UITableView). Can i make row menu like it? Thanks :)

Comment: I thinks answer of Yannick Compernol is what i'm looking for. I'm trying another way, but it worse than using UIGestureRecognizer. I'll post both of 2 ways latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed just a `UIView` with a background image and some controls/views on it.

If you want to get a similar behavior in which you swipe over the cell to reveal that view, you could use the new iOS4 `UIGestureRecognizer` to look for a swipe over the cell. Once it detects a swipe you can use a view animation to slide the new view in.

Link: [UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks Yannick Compernol,  i'll try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an example project make a "Swipe to Reveal Menu like Tweetie". Look at it if you want to build a Menu like Tweetie.

http://thermoglobalnuclearwar.com/opensource/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a normal view with a specific background image and some buttons laid out horizontally.